# Help with Inverse function example questions

Tags: functions

Question 24 GCSE past paper:

> The function $g$ is such that $g(x)=2x^2-20x+9$ where $x\geq 5$.
>
> (b) Express the inverse function $g^{-1}$ in the form $g^{-1}(x)=\dots$.

Hi hope you are doing well,
I found the mark scheme but I didn't really understand why the square was completed.
Also, why is $x$ defined as $\geq5$?
Help would be appreciated
*if it gets approved*

Comment: What have you tried? If the domain was $x\in \mathbb R$, would the function even be invertible?

Comment: The $x\geq 5$ is to throw away a piece of the many-to-one function such that what is left is one-to-one. Only a one-to-one function can have an inverse. There is a set of GCSE lessons on functions with teaching videos too at http://www.numberwonder.co.uk/Pages/Page9002.html